# What is .config/user?

Tags: dconf

As far as I know, the Dconf configuration is stored in `~/.config/dconf/user`. However, I just noticed that I also have `~/.config/user` which has not been used for a while:

```
~> ls -l ~/.config/user ~/.config/dconf/user
-rw-rw-r-- 1 andrea andrea 56059 may 14 17:41 /home/andrea/.config/dconf/user
-rw-rw-r-- 1 andrea andrea 51750 jan 29 23:36 /home/andrea/.config/user
```

They are both GVariant databases:

```
~> file ~/.config/user ~/.config/dconf/user
/home/andrea/.config/user:       GVariant Database file, version 0
/home/andrea/.config/dconf/user: GVariant Database file, version 0
```

What is `~/.config/user`? Is it maybe an old version of `~/.config/dconf/user` that was migrated to a different path in a recent version of Ubuntu? Or is it something different?

Can I safely delete it?

Comment: How it got in ~/.config who knows but has no value so you can delete it

Comment: Well, you can always do `strings /home/andrea/.config/user` or `hexdump -C /home/andrea/.config/user` to see what's inside that file

Comment: @Serg, sure... I could use any of the standard forensics trick. But the question is not about what is inside the file (I know it's a GVariant db file, quite similar to the other one). My question could be re-stated as: does my Ubuntu make use of it? Did any previous version of Ubuntu make use of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up deleting the file and nothing seems to have broken.

`~/.config/user` is not a standard Ubuntu configuration file.

The most plausible cause for its existence is that I wanted to make a backup copy of `~/.config/dconf/user` and then I forgot about it.